# Toyota Tazz 1.3 clutch grunding

Tags: toyota, clutch

Yesterday was driving my 2003 Toyota Tazz, when I was changing to 3rd gear the clutch didn't come up. Stopped the car and tried to put it into 1st gear, but gear couldn't move. Switched it off and put it to 1st gear and start it and there was a grunding sound and I drove home with 1st gear.

Do you think its clutch plate or gear box?

Comment: By "grunding" would I think that the same as "grinding" as in you are grinding gears when trying to shift?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your throwout mechanism is toast. I'm going to assume your throwout mechanism is hydraulic based, which means one of several things.

First, you could have lost hydraulic fluid in the system. Check the master cylinder reservoir to ensure there is enough fluid to actuate the clutch. If it is low here, you can try to fill it up to where it's supposed to be, but there will probably be an underlying problem or leakage which has caused the master cylinder reservoir to be low. Some systems utilize the brake fluid reservoir as a dual purpose reservoir. If the brake fluid is low, it might not have enough fluid to actuate the master/slave of the clutch.

Second, which would be easier to diagnose, the hose which feeds from the master to the slave may have an issue. Check the hose for wetness.

Thirdly, the slave cylinder may be leaking. If the throwout bearing has a hydraulic sleeve which resides inside the bell housing, this could be harder to diagnose. If it has a slave cylinder located outside of the bell housing and utilizes a fork to actuate the clutch, check it for leakage.

**If the throwout mechanism is cable based**, you'll need to see if the cable has been broken and will not transfer the pedal motion down to the throwout bearing. You'd need to track it from the pedal all the way down to the bell housing. See if it is moving along with the pedal as you actuate it (pull it back and push it forward). You should be able to locate it at the top of the pedal assembly. Have a second person checking either under the hood (if the throwout arm is located up top) or underneath to see what movement can be seen. If you are moving on your end and the cable is not moving on the other, get a replacement cable. They are usually fairly easy to replace.